# Sorting with collections in java

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I have a tricky question in sorting with collection.

I have a HashMap which contains some thing like the following

```
HashMap<String,QuoteBean> mapToSort=new HashMap<<String,QuoteBean>();
```

QuoteBean is basically a java bean which has properties with setter and getter methods
Which looks like the following.

```
//class QuoteBean defination

Class QuoteBean implements Serializable{
  private BigDecimal currentPricel
  private BigDecimal  change;
  private BigDecimal TotalChange;
  private String symbol;

//with getter and setter methods  

}//end of the class
```

Now when i get the values from the map i usually get it like this

```
Collection values=mapToSort.values();//which will return all the values in the map
```

This values is basically a collection of QuoteBean objects.
I want to sort the beans before sending it to the client.
Now i can use the comparator interface and sort it ..
But the problem is the sorting criteria changes frequently .
I mean some time the client wants to sort with symbol,some times the client wants with change some times with total gain.
The criteria changes very often.
Is there a way to write the " compare " function to overload and which will satisfy all the conditions...

Is there any good way of solving this problem..

I would really appreciate if some one can reply to this topic

Thanks,

Answer (score 6):

Yes. Implement the [`java.util.Comparator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface and use the overloaded method: `Collections.sort(list, comparator)` (you will need to create a new `List` from the elements of the collection, for example `new ArrayList(collection)`)

So you can have:

```
public CurrentPriceQuoteComparator implements Comparator<QuoteBean> {
    @Override
    public int compare(QuoteBean b1, QuoteBean b2) { // implement comparison }
}

public ChangeQuoteComparator implements Comparator<QuoteBean> {
    @Override
    public int compare(QuoteBean b1, QuoteBean b2) { // implement comparison }
}
```

And then use `Collections.sort(list, ChangeQuoteComparator.INSTANCE);`

Note that it is a good practice to declare a singleton instance of each comparator, instead of instantiating it each time:

```
public static final ChangeQuoteComparator INSTANCE = 
     new ChangeQuoteComparator();
```

---

To extend things a little more, you can define an `enum` with the different comparison types:

```
public enum ComparisonType {
   CHANGE, CURRENT_PRICE; // etc..
}
```

and define a `Map` to match each comparison type with the appropriate comparator:

```
private static final Map<ComparisonType, Comparator<QuoteBean>> comparators = 
      new HashMapMap<ComparisonType, Comparator<QuoteBean>>();

static {
   comparators.put(ComparisonType.CHANGE, ChangeQuoteComparator.INSTANCE);
   comparators.put(ComparisonType.CURENT_PRICE, 
           CurrentPriceQuoteComparator.INSTANCE);
}
```

and then let the client specify which comparison he'd like

```
 public List<QuoteBean> getOrdered(ComparisonType type, // other criteria) {
     List<QuoteBean> list = new ArrayList<QuoteBean>(getQuotesCollection());
     Collections.sort(list, comparators.get(type));
     return list;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Comparator` and create either multiple implementations, or you can use a dynamic implementation where you change the way it works by setting parameters on it.

---

For the multiple implementations you can take a look at @Bozho answer.

For the dynamic implementation you could do something like that :

```
public class DynamicComparator implements Comparator<QuoteBean> {
    public boolean compareCurrentPricel = false;
    public boolean change = false;

    //Setters for the booleans

    @Override
    public int compare(QuoteBean b1, QuoteBean b2) {
        int currentSort = 0;
        if(compareCurrentPricel && currentSort == 0){
            currentSort = compareCurrentPrice1(b1, b2);
        }
        if(change && currentSort == 0){
            currentSort = compareChange(b1, b2);
        }
    }
}
```

Or even better :

```
public class MultipleComparators<T> implements Comparator<T> {
    public List<Comparator<? super T>> comparators;

    public MultipleComparators(List<Comparator<? super T>> comparators){
        this.comparators = comparators;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(T b1, T b2) {
        int returned = 0;
        for(Comparator<? super T> c : comparators){
            returned = c.compare(b1, b2);
            if(returned != 0){
                break;
            }
        }
        return returned;
    }
}
```

This way you can use any comparator you want and even multiple comparators which will be executed in the right order.

Comment: @Colin Hebert When you say multipleimplementation ..Could mind giving an example or pusdo code what do you mean by that..

Comment: @Colin Hebert could mind explaining the dynamic implementation with an example ...

Comment: @user436175, now there is an example. But after re-reading the original question, I might have misunderstood the question. I thought you wanted also compare on different elements at the same time. But still it answers the question :)

Comment: public class DynamicComparator implements Comparator<QuoteBean>{}

Comment: Not sure why i get an exception called classcast exception

Comment: update your question, and post your code. Or if it has really changed create a new question.

Comment: I mean when a call like collection.sort(list,new DynamicComparator()) and the list contains and quotebean objects and not sure why i get class casr exception ..and says can not convert string to quotebean

Answer (score 1):

You will have to write a comparator each for every situation and depending on the client requirement you can choose the comparator.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution to this would be to use a beancomparator object from apache commons. You can do something like

`BeanComparator comparator = new BeanComparator("currentPricel");
Collections.sort(yourlisthere, comparator);`

or you can directly do a

`Collections.sort(yourlisthere, new BeanComparator("currentPricel"));`